# mongodb: return an array of document ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to query mongodb to return array of matching document id values, without the related keys?

Please consider following 'parent' data structur:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3a7"),
  "name": "Peter",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "joe"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3b6"),
  "name": "Marry",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "joe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would to query for an array of parent _ids whose children have the name "joe"

For provided sample data, I would like the following output returned from mongo:

```
[ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3a7"), ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3b6")]
```

I know that I can query for an output like this, which also contains the keys

```
[{"_id": ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3a7")}, {"_id": ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3b6")}]
```

However I need to push above array to another document with an update operation like this:

```
db.statistic.update({"date": today}, {$push: {"children": [ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3a7"), ObjectId("52448e4697fb2b775cb5c3b6")]}}, true, false)
```

I would like to avoid sorting out the document structure, in case it is possible to just return an array containing the appropriate values using mongo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be possible by

```
db.coll.distinct("_id", {"children.name": "joe"})
```

Comment: Cand this be done somehow using the aggregate framework?